# How to limit the height of Checklist box

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have 65 items to be displayed in a checkbox list. The height of the table row having the checklist box is 60px. Please suggest ways to limit the height of the checklistbox contained in the row.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your Checkboxlist into a fixed size area by putting it in a div
such as this:

```
<div id="Layer1" style="position:relative;width:350px;height:200px;
overflow:scroll;">CheckBoxList Goes Here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use max-height css property or just height property on the checkbox list style attribute.